# ansible dynamic hosts refuse to use custom interpreter

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm trying to provision new machines on AWS with ec2 module
and to update my hosts file locally so that the next tasks would already use the hosts file.

So, provisioning isn't and issue and even the creation of the local host file:

```
- name: Provision a set of instances
      ec2:
         key_name: AWS
         region: eu-west-1
         group: default
         instance_type: t2.micro
         image: ami-6f587e1c # For Ubuntu 14.04 LTS use ami-b9b394ca # For Ubuntu 16.04 LTS use ami-6f587e1c
         wait: yes
         volumes:
          - device_name: /dev/xvda
            volume_type: gp2
            volume_size: 50
            wait: true
         count: 2
         vpc_subnet_id: subnet-xxxxxxxx
         assign_public_ip: yes
         instance_tags:
            Name: Ansible
      register: ec2

    - name: Add all instance private IPs to host group
      add_host:
          hostname: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
          ansible_ssh_user: ubuntu
          groups: aws
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

    - local_action: file path=./hosts state=absent
      ignore_errors: yes

    - local_action: file path=./hosts state=touch

    - local_action: lineinfile line="[all]" insertafter=EOF dest=./hosts

    - local_action: lineinfile line="{{ item.private_ip }}  ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3" insertafter=EOF dest=./hosts
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

    - name: Wait for SSH to come up
      wait_for:
          host: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
          port: 22
          delay: 60
          timeout: 600
          state: started
      with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

    - name: refreshing inventory cache
      meta: refresh_inventory

- hosts: all
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
    - command: hostname -i
```

However the next task which is a simple print of hostname -i (just for the test)
fails because it can't find on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Python 2.7 (there is python3)
For that, in my dynamic host file I add the following line:

```
ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3
```

But it seems that ansible ignore it and goes straight to python 2.7 which is missing.

I've tried to reload the inventory file

```
meta: refresh_inventory
```

but that didn't helped either.
What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Note that python 3 support in ansible is still a bit flaky: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/python_3_support.html

Comment: @SztupY - Yes I know, I just wonder what others do if they need to use Ubuntu 16.04 that doesn't come with python2.x ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why the refresh did not work but I suggest setting it in the `add_host` section, it takes any variable.

```
- name: Add all instance private IPs to host group
  add_host:
      hostname: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
      ansible_ssh_user: ubuntu
      groups: aws
      ansible_python_interpreter: "/usr/bin/python3"
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
```

Also i find it useful to debug with this task

```
- debug: var=hostvars[inventory_hostname]
```